# Django QuerySet returning multiple objects (filtered on UNIQUE key)

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-mysql

I am facing a very weird issue with Django ORM. I am having a below queryset which is expected to return single object (as `my_unique_key` is unique value), but it is returning multiple instance of the same object (check list of primary keys):

```
my_model_queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(q, obj_key='my_unique_key')
# print my_model_queryset.values_list('id', flat=True)
# [63, 63, 63]
```

where `q` is `Q()` function with content:

```
some_keys = [u'yJodCsWTTYyi1NMW', u'MOAKea3MSVilbxVU', u'ZXy9ONNQ1MBAMzFT', 
             u'cuDAuxnAFiuItzDR', u'ZzULRBixdpW9MzC8', u'pYsXxXET0mTPgzl8', 
             u'C4LmGqhZeILPpgAq', u'gxbkRaMKxySOfkIm']
primary_keys = [6273L, 5974L, 6342L, 4076L, 4490L, 2892L, 3921L, 1554L, 1046L, 
                5977L, 5946L, 6269L]

q = (Q(cf_object__obj_key__in=some_keys)|
     Q(related_my_mapping__cf_object__obj_key__in=some_keys)|
     Q(id__in=primary_keys))
```

My model structure is like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    obj_key = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    cf_object = models.ForeignKey('CFModel', null=True, related_name='related_my_model')
    # ...blah...blah...blah...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'my_model'


class CFModel(models.Model):
    obj_key = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    # ...blah...blah...blah...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'cf_model'


class MyModelCFModelMapping(models.Model):
    my_object = models.ForeignKey('MyModel', null=True, related_name='related_my_mapping')
    cf_object = models.ForeignKey('CFModel', null=True, related_name='related_my_mapping')
    # ...blah...blah...blah...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'my_model_cf_model_mapping'
```

However, it works perfectly fine if I remove one condition from my `q` function as:

```
q = (Q(cf_object__obj_key__in=some_keys)|
     Q(id__in=primary_keys))
```

*Any idea on why Django is behaving unexpectedly will be helpful?*